# How to Remove Synergy from Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, synergy, steam

Hi I don't remember installing synergy but it's been in my computer for a while. However now since I don't have much space in my computer, I can't afford it taking up any space. But I couldn't uninstall it, as well as pinball arcade. How do I do it? I have just uninstalled steam, does it affect the uninstallment?

Answer (score 1):

A program on OS X can usually be uninstalled in the following ways:

1. Redownload the program, and see if there is an uninstaller inside of the download
2. Drag the application to the trash

If your hard drive is filling up, uninstalling programs likely won't make much of a dent. First try this:

- Delete items out of Downloads Directory
- Use [grand perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) to find the largest files
- Purchase a program like [clusters](http://clustersapp.com) to compress your drive
- Buy a larger hard drive